# Changing primary palette color, when using KivyMD, has no effect on buttons

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language

So I'm trying to build an app using **Kivy** and, recently, I learned about **KivyMD** but got stuck. When I change primary palette color it stays blue for every button, but changes for *MDDropDownMenu*. I tried using it both before and in build method, and still it worked only for *MDDropDownMenu*. What can cause this?

main.py:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from root.ModelPrep import validate_params, change_koatuu, prep_params, load_regression
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.toast import toast


class MainWindow(Screen):...
class LoadWindow(Screen):...
class ResultWindow(Screen):...


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


# kv_non_md = Builder.load_file('deepeval_non_md.kv')
kv_md = Builder.load_file('deepeval_md.kv')


class DeepEval(App):

    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    title = 'DeepEval'
    main_widget = None

    menu_items = []

    def callback_for_menu_items(self, *args):
        toast(args[0])

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Teal'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
        self.menu_items = [{
                "viewclass": "MDMenuItem",
                "text": "Example item %d" % i,
                "callback": self.callback_for_menu_items,
            }
            for i in range(15)
        ]
        return kv_md


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DeepEval().run()
```

deepeval_md.kv:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.uix.menu.MDDropdownMenu

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    LoadWindow:
    ResultWindow:

<MainWindow>
    name: 'main'

    koatuu_obl_cent: koatuu_obl_cent
    koatuu_city: koatuu_city
    kitchen_area: kitchen_area
    qt_room: qt_room
    floor: floor
    qt_floor: qt_floor
    total_area: total_area
    living_area: living_area
    year_building: year_building

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        size: root.width, root.height

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            height: 350
            width: 225
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: None
            spacing: 22.5

            MDTextFieldRect:
                id: total_area
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param12"
                halign: 'center'
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            MDTextFieldRect:
                id: kitchen_area
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param1"
                halign: 'center'
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            MDTextFieldRect:
                id: living_area
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param1"
                halign: 'center'
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            MDTextFieldRect:
                id: qt_room
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param1"
                halign: 'center'
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            MDTextFieldRect:
                id: floor
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param1"
                halign: 'center'
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            MDTextFieldRect:
                id: qt_floor
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param1"
                halign: 'center'
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            MDTextFieldRect:
                id: year_building
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param1"
                halign: 'center'
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                id: koatuu_obl_cent
                text: 'Open popup'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
                on_release: MDDropdownMenu(items=app.menu_items, width_mult=3).open(self)
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                id: koatuu_city
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
                text: 'Open popup'
                on_release: MDDropdownMenu(items=app.menu_items, width_mult=3).open(self)
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: "center"
            anchor_y: "bottom"
            padding: 0,0,0,25

            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                text: "Calculate"
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 50
                on_press: app.root.current = 'load'
                on_release:
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just change the button color using this:
MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
md_bg_color: [0, 0, 0, .3]

I just hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to add an import line of 'from kivymd.app import MDApp'.   See https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

While **[KivyMD](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD)** is in *alpha* status, it may contain bugs. Widgets in **KivyMD 0.102.0** set their colors on initialization. In your case the best way to fix it will be loading .kv file inside *build* function:

```py
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        # ...
        kv_md = Builder.load_file("deepeval_md.kv")
        return kv_md
```